# C# - Incrementing StockNumber

Tags: c#, increment

Each class in the StockItem/HeavyStockItem/CarEngine hierarchy contains two constructors.

StockItem contains a static field which maintains the value of the last stock number used (initialised to 10000).

One of StockItem’s constructors ignores this field and receives the stock number as a parameter this is to cater for entering stock received prior to this system being implemented. 
It also receives the Description and CostPrice as parameters.

The second of StockItem’s constructors uses this static field to automatically generate a stock number, and hence does not need a stock number argument passed. It just receives the Description and CostPrice parameters.

Each of StockItem’s subclasses follows this model, invoking the super constructor appropriate to the task, and processing the added argument (specific to the class) accordingly.

```
class StockItem
{

    public static int LastStockNumber = 10000;
    public int StockNumber;
    public string Description;
    public float CostPrice;

    public StockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice) : this(Description, CostPrice)
    {
        this.StockNumber = StockNumber;
        this.Description = Description;
        this.CostPrice = CostPrice;
    }

    public StockItem(string Description, float CostPrice)
    {
        LastStockNumber++;
        StockNumber = LastStockNumber;

    }
```

```
 class HeavyStockItem : StockItem
{
    private float Weight;

    public HeavyStockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight) : base(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice)
    {
        this.Weight = Weight;
    }

    public HeavyStockItem(string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight) : base(Description, CostPrice)
    {
    }
```

```
class CarEngine : HeavyStockItem
{
    private string EngineNumber;

    public CarEngine(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight, string EngineNumber) : base(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice, Weight)
    {
        this.EngineNumber = EngineNumber;
    }

    public CarEngine(string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight, string EngineNumber) : base(Description, CostPrice, Weight)
    {        
    }
```

Currently my code is incrementing +1 for every StockItem but I want it to only increment if NO StockNumber was specified.

Newbie Coder here :)

Cheers!

Comment: My stock numbers need to be 10000, 10001, 10002 and so on whereas currently the stock numbers are 10000, 10002, 10004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes to get the results I was after:

```
class StockItem
{
    //StockItem Variables
    public static int LastStockNumber = 10000;
    internal int StockNumber;
    internal string Description;
    internal float CostPrice;


    //Constructor - Ignores static field and receives the StockNumber as a parameter
    public StockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice) 
    {
        this.StockNumber = StockNumber;
        this.Description = Description;
        this.CostPrice = CostPrice;
    }

    //Constructor -  Uses this static field to automatically generate a StockNumber and increments +1 to LastStockNumber
    public StockItem(string Description, float CostPrice) : this(StockItem.LastStockNumber, Description, CostPrice)
    {           
        this.StockNumber = LastStockNumber;
        LastStockNumber++;
        this.CostPrice = CostPrice;
        this.Description = Description;
    }
```

```
class HeavyStockItem : StockItem //Extended to StockItem Class
{
    //Variable
    internal float Weight;

    //Constructor - Ignores static field and receives the StockNumber and adds Weight to the parameters
    public HeavyStockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight): base(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice)
    {
        this.Weight = Weight;
    }
    //Constructor
    public HeavyStockItem(string Description, float CostPrice, float   Weight): base(Description, CostPrice)
    {
        this.Weight = Weight;
    }
```

```
class CarEngine : HeavyStockItem //Extended to HeavyStockItem Class
{
    //Variables
    internal string EngineNumber;

    //Constructor
    public CarEngine(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight, string EngineNumber): base(StockNumber, Description, CostPrice, Weight)
    {
        this.EngineNumber = EngineNumber;
    }

    //Constructor
    public CarEngine(string Description, float CostPrice, float Weight, string EngineNumber): base(Description, CostPrice, Weight)
    {
        this.EngineNumber = EngineNumber;
    }
```

I made changes to the Contructor chaining as suggested and it now increments correctly. Thankyou for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `: this(Description, CostPrice)` from the `StockItem(int, string, float)` constructor.

This is causing the code flow to also call the other constructor in the `StockItem` base class, consequently `LastStockNumber` is always being incremented regardless of a explicit stock number being injected.

Comment: He needs to increment the StockItem.LastStockNumber when calling StockItem(Description, CostPrice). So the solution is actually to change the direction of constructor chain.

Comment: @AwakeningByte That is one possibility, but the immediate cause is as I specified in my answer. The increment upon every creation is caused by the current ctor chaining. The most optimal fix for that is up to the OP and how he wants to structure the code - I am not making any assumptions about that.

Comment: My stock numbers need to be 10000, 10001, 10002 and so on whereas currently the stock numbers are 10000, 10002, 10004.

Comment: @MeLzA If your stock number is incrementing by 2 then that indicates that you've done something else other than what was suggested. Maybe you need to post your updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the direction of constructor chain can do what you want

```
class StockItem
{

  public static int LastStockNumber = 10000;
  public int StockNumber;
  public string Description;
  public float CostPrice;

  public StockItem(int StockNumber, string Description, float CostPrice) 
  {
    this.StockNumber = StockNumber;
    this.Description = Description;
    this.CostPrice = CostPrice;
  }

  public StockItem(string Description, float CostPrice): this(StockItem.LastStockNumber, Description, CostPrice)
  {
      StockItem.LastStockNumber += 1;
  }
```

Comment: After making the changes it now only returns the LastStockNumber as the default static int of 10000.

Comment: Still returning 10000 for LastStockNumber and not incrementing.

Comment: My stock numbers need to be 10000, 10001, 10002 and so on whereas currently the stock numbers are 10000, 10002, 10004.